# regex - each digit equal to next or previous

Tags: regex

I need a regex code (for egrep) to match only lines where a digit is equal to the previous one or the next one.

ex: 66688833777443344477774488555

but not: 262227723336339337775533777

Any help please?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: What language are you using? Some languages don't support lookahead/lookbehind regexes...

Comment: @WayneWerner: No need for lookaround.

Comment: I don't know what the language is called but its for use in the BASH shell, with the command 'egrep'. @AndyLester i would love to, but i have no idea on how to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about this for a while. In essence your problem means: Match a number where each digit is immediately repeated at least once.

Now if you know that `([0-9])\1+` will match one such group of digits (like `22` or `777`), then you're halfway there.

The next step is to match one or more of these groups. For that, you need another `+` quantifier plus another pair of [parentheses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that encloses the to-be-repeated group:

```
(([0-9])\2+)+
```

Note that the backreference changed to `\2` because `([0-9])` is now the second (inner) group.

Finally, to make sure that the entire line matches, we need to use some [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
^(([0-9])\2+)+$
```

Comment: Ok, but that lists every line with 1 or more pair, i need to list the lines where the whole number is made out of only pairs.

Comment: i know + means '1 or more time's, * '0 or more times', but is there any character for 'all times'?

Comment: @user2883717: `+` is sufficient. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

A solution using look around `^(?:(\d)(?:(?=\1)|(?<=\1{2})))+$` :

```
^    # start of input
  (?:    # start not capturing group for repetition for each decimal
    (\d)    # any decimal captured in a group
    (?:
      (?=\1)     # positif look ahead for an ocurrence of the capture in the group
      |            # or
      (?<=\1{2}) # positif look behind for the matched decimal and the same decimal one position before
     )
  )+     # end of repetition group for each decimal
$     #end of input
```